# How to configure FEIGN on the client to authenticate against a REST service using SEEDSTACK framework?

Tags: java, feign, seedstack

I would like to call a REST web service from my client application using FEIGN and SEEDSTACK. The web service, which is developed with SEEDSATCK too, is configured with the following authentication method: "filters: [ authcBasic ]"

**How to configure or program the client to get the authentication right? How to pass the USER and PASSWORD information?**

client FEIGNAPI class:

```
@FeignApi
public interface neosdServer {

    @RequestLine("GET /file/getfilesprop")
    List<NeosdFile> getfilesprop();

    @RequestLine("GET /file/getfiles")
    List<String> getfiles();
}
```

client APPLICATION.YAML

```
feign:
  endpoints:
    neosdClient.interfaces.rest.neosdServer: 
      baseUrl: http://localhost:8080
      encoder: feign.jackson.JacksonEncoder
      decoder: feign.jackson.JacksonDecoder
```

server APPLICATION.YAML

```
  web:
    urls:
      -
        pattern: /file/getfiles
        filters: [ authcBasic, 'roles[read]' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The current SeedStack integration doesn't support configuring interceptors on feign builders for now. Instead, to do authentication you can specify a header in your Feign interface with the `@Headers` annotation (example for basic authentication):

```
@FeignApi
@Headers({"Authorization: Basic {credentials}"})
public interface neosdServer {

    @RequestLine("GET /file/getfilesprop")
    List<NeosdFile> getfilesprop(@Param("credentials") String credentials);

    @RequestLine("GET /file/getfiles")
    List<String> getfiles(@Param("credentials") String credentials);
}
```

Note that `@Headers` can also be used on individual methods.

You will then have to pass the credentials as method parameter. An example implementation, with credentials coming from your application configuration, coudl be:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Configuration("myApp.credentials.user")
    private String username;
    @Configuration("myApp.credentials.password")
    private String password;
    @Inject
    private NeoSdClient client;

    public void myMethod() {
        List<String> files = client.getFiles(encodeCredentials());
    }

    private String encodeCredentials() {
        return BaseEncoding
                .base64()
                .encode((username + ":" + password)
                        .getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

I created an issue on the Feign add-on repository to track the implementation of interceptor support: https://github.com/seedstack/feign-addon/issues/4.

Comment: Thank you for that quick help. I have implemented that solution in my code successfully.